# Plotting a Time/Value graph in Python using matplotlib

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, plot, graph

In my software, people will enter a time and a energy consumption value. There will be as many entries of this tuple as the user wants, so the graph will need to be flexible. Ex:

`[('12:25', 98.0), ('13:48', 96.3), ('14:47', 85.0), ('16:25', 88.1), ...]`

I already got this part. Users enter the data on the screen, I make some data-checking, filtering and the result is a list like the above. Now, I need to plot this list into a graph.

Thank you and have a nice day. :)

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks_and_spines/date_demo_rrule.html

Comment: @fdireito Your example shows graph plotting with dates. I can't, at least for now, transform it to a solution with time.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Now I'm going to look how to add labels and stuff. :)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_graph(times, values):
    """ Plots the graph. """
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    plt.plot(times, values)
    ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(rotation=30, labelsize=10)

    plt.show()
```